# How to Discretize the Following Region Using Reasonable Bounds?

Tags: mesh, implicit

I want to accurately discretize the implicit equation $x^2+x+y^2+\sin(4xy)+\sin(3xy)=3.9$.

To get the whole discretized shape, I'm forced to use oversized bounds `{x,-70,80}` and `{y,-70,80}`

```
curve = DiscretizeRegion[
  ImplicitRegion[
   x^2 + x + y^2 + Sin[4*x*y] + Sin[3*x* y] == 
    3.9, {{x, -80, 70}, {y, -80, 70}}]]
```

[image]

If I reasonable bounds such as `{x,-3,3}` and `{y,-3,3}`, I get the following.

[image]

What adjustments can be made and how will this improve the accuracy?

Comment: `{{x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}}`

Comment: @DavidG.Stork How come this works but the others don't.

Comment: *(I'm new to Mathematica; sorry if this is a silly question.)* Why do you have `x^2 + x + y^2` in your code but just $x^2 + y^2$ in the equation at the top of your answer? Why the extra `x` term?

Comment: @Nodon'tshownmyrealname Because I'm careless! I edited the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give [`DiscretizeRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretizeRegion) a second argument specifying bounds:

```
DiscretizeRegion[
    ImplicitRegion[
        x^2+x+y^2+Sin[4*x*y]+Sin[3*x*y]==3.9,
        {{x,-3,3},{y,-3,3}}
    ],
    {{-3,3},{-3,3}}
]
```

[image]

Comment: ah.. note if you do `RegionBounds` on the intermediate `ImplicitRegion` it returns an incorrect result.

Answer (score 5):

making that parameter exact seems to fix things:

```
curve = DiscretizeRegion[
  ImplicitRegion[
   x^2 + x + y^2 + Sin[4*x*y] + Sin[3*x*y] == 
    39/10, {{x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}}]]
```

[image]

note with the exact parameter and your origial "oversize" bounds you get a poor discretisation:

[image]

( remedied with `MaxElementSize` , etc )

Comment: I tried your code but I doesn't give the full picture.

Comment: For some reason only entering `{x,-5,5}` and `{y,-5,-5}` works.

Comment: there seems to be a version issue.  Works for me with 10.1 , not with 11.1.

Answer (score 3):

```
DiscretizeRegion[
  ImplicitRegion[
  x^2 + x + y^2 + Sin[4 x y] + Sin[3 x y] == 3.9, 
  {{x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}}],
  AccuracyGoal -> 8]
```

[image]

Comment: How come `{x,-5,5}` and `{x,-5,5}` works but not `{-4,3}` and `{-3,3}` does not work.