# Is there a Bug in Mathematica 11.1 with RegionCentroid?

Tags: bugs, regions, implicit

**Bug introduced in 11.1 and fixed in 11.2.0**

---

I solved for the centroid of $x^2+y^2+\sin(4x)+\sin(4y)=4$

```
J = RegionCentroid[
  DiscretizeRegion[
   ImplicitRegion[
    x^2 + y^2 + Sin[4*x] + Sin[4*y] == 4, {{x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}}], 
   AccuracyGoal -> 8]]
```

But end up with

> {-1.90037, 0.230247}

With a lower accuracy

```
J = RegionCentroid[
      DiscretizeRegion[
       ImplicitRegion[
        x^2 + y^2 + Sin[4*x] + Sin[4*y] == 4, {{x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}}], 
       AccuracyGoal -> 4]]
```

I still get

```
{-1.90035, 0.230246}
```

Which makes no sense.

[image]

---

**Edit**

`DescretizeRegion` doesn't work without adding bounds `{{-3,3},{-3,3}}`

```
DiscretizeRegion[
 ImplicitRegion[
  x^2+y^2+Sin[4x]+Sin[4y]==4, {{x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}}], {{-3, 
   3}, {-3, 3}}, AccuracyGoal -> 8]
```

[image]

This was presented in a [previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/162674/how-to-discretize-the-following-region-using-reasonable-bounds)

---

However, with `RegionCentroid` I still get

> {-1.90037, 0.230247}

Comment: Please only tag things `[bugs]` if they've been confirmed by WRI. It's a community standard, but makes our lives better.

Comment: Your `AccuracyGoal` is throwing things off. The curve is over-discretized. Drop it and it'll work for you.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. I get `{-1.90035, 0.230246}`

Comment: See my answer. It works for me.

Comment: Actually wait even at `AccuracyGoal -> 8` I can't reproduce this. I think you've got some cached definition or something...

Comment: Bug as heck - all proposed solutions, and the OP's code, work fine on v10.4; v11.1 messes things up. Adding the tag.

Comment: I reproduce the issue with version 11.1.1 on Windows 7 x64. Version 10.4.1 and 11.2.0 produce the expected result: `{-0.108616, -0.108616}`. So the bug was introduced in version 11.1 and fixed in 11.2.0. Added the bug header.

Answer (score 5):

> DescretizeRegion works fine

I cannot reproduce this.  To me, it seems that the bug lies clearly with the [`DiscretizeRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretizeRegion.html) function:

```
$Version
DiscretizeRegion[
 ImplicitRegion[
  x^2 + y^2 + Sin[4*x] + Sin[4*y] == 4, {{x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}}]]
(* "11.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (May 30, 2017)" *)
```

[image]

Given the above region, `RegionCentroid` is behaving properly,

```
Show[%, Graphics @ Point @ RegionCentroid@%]
```

[image]

On MacOS, this bug is fixed in version 11.2

Comment: Actually, with `DescretizeRegion` I added the bounds `{{-3,3},{-3,3}]` to `DiscretizeRegion[
 ImplicitRegion[
  S16[x, y] == 0.4, {{x, -2.5, 1}, {y, -2.5, 2.5}}], {{-2.5, 
   1}, {-2.5, 2.5}}, AccuracyGoal -> 8]
` but with `RegionCentroid` this does not work.

Comment: This was mentioned in my [previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/162674/how-to-discretize-the-following-region-using-reasonable-bounds)

Comment: Never mind, in my first comment, `RegionCentroid` does work but still gives the incorrect output.

Comment: I get the correct output from your `DescretizeRegion` code with versions 10.0.1, 10.4.1, 11.1.1 and 11.2.0 on Windows 7 x64. The behavior seems to be platform-dependent.

Answer (score 3):

Try `<=4`

```
    r = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 + Sin[4*x] + Sin[4*y] <= 4, {x, y}];
    center = RegionCentroid[DiscretizeRegion[r]];
    Show[RegionPlot[r, PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}], Graphics[Point@center]]

center={-0.0848068, -0.084911}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you even reproduce the original issue? I can't.

Comment: Can you get the coordinates?

Comment: coordinates is `RegionCentroid[DiscretizeRegion[r]]`

Comment: `RegionCentroid[
 DiscretizeRegion[
  ImplicitRegion[
   x^2 + y^2 + Sin[4*x] + Sin[4*y] == 4, {{x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}}]]]` produces  {-1.89998, 0.230282} on my machine with MMA 11.1

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci I get the same with version 11.1.1 on Windows 7 x64. Version 11.2.0 produces `{-0.108357, -0.108372}`.